# Extract a changing number from a Google Sheets string with a formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I regularly get an update which ends up in a Google Sheets file. In order to use the data from this string (see underneath), I want to extract the third number. The rest of the data is less relevant. I want to do this in Google Sheets, so I need the *'250'* from the sentence and save it in a new column. What makes this extra challenging, is the change in values. For instance, one day it could be 4000 and the next only 10.

> "Here is your daily digest. Daily New Customers Report -  NL Jan 17,
> 2021 Here is your daily digest. **250** +28.1% New Customers
> Unsubscribe from this."

I tried it with the underneath formula in Sheets, but this does not take into account the different amount of digits the number could take.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(isblank(B2:B)," ",REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B, "\d{3}?")))
```

I hope you can help me with this!

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B2:B),REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B,"^(?:\D*\d+){2}\D*(\d+)"),""))
```

Or a little less verbose:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B,"^(?:\D*\d+){2}\D*(\d+)"),,),"")
```

---

A littel bit more explaination on the pattern itself:

```
^(?:\D*\d+){2}\D*(\d+)
```

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `(?:` - Open non-capturing group.

  - `\D*\d+` - Zero or more non-digits up to 1+ digits.
  - `){2}` - Close non-capture group and match it twice.
- `\D*` - Zero or more non-digits.
- `(\d+)` - 1st Capture group holding 1+ digits.

See the online RE2 [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uDtJXO/1).

<sub>**Note1:** We don't want to use a capture group on the 1st repeated pattern since `REGEXEXTRACT()` will extract the 1st capture group.</sub>

<sub>**Note2:** It could also be written as: `^\D*\d\D*\d+\D*(\d)` which is less verbose, but IMO not as clean as the use of groupings.</sub>

Comment: You just beat me to it! Looks good. Could you remind me what ?: means plz?

Comment: Thanks @TomSharpe. I edited the answer to explain the regex pattern.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="",,REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B, "est. (\d+) ")*1))
```

[image]

---

or shorter:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B, "est. (\d+) ")*1))
```

[image]

Comment: That's a nice option also if the text is standardized like that =)